# on the order problems in the classpath with IDEA && Spring Boot && Maven

Tags: maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

```
/u~u/.rc-ubuntu/.rc-bins/.jdk/bin/java 
    -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:38537,suspend=y,server=n 
    -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 
    -noverify 
    -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=42079 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
    -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost 
    -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain 
    -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true 
    -javaagent:/home/zhangle/ileler/bins/ideaj/idea-IU-181.4203.550/lib/rt/debugger-agent.jar=file:/tmp/capture.props 
    -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
    -classpath /u~u/.rc-ubuntu/.rc-bins/.jdk/jre/....jar:/u~u/.../target/classes:/repo/a.jar:/repo/b.jar
```

The above is the output command in IDEAJ when the Spring-Boot project is running.
I have a question about **classpath order** now.(`-classpath /u~u/.rc-ubuntu/.rc-bins/.jdk/jre/....jar:/u~u/.../target/classes:/repo/a.jar:/repo/b.jar`)

about:`/repo/a.jar:/repo/b.jar`

My project uses **maven** to manage dependency

Now I want to know how the order of the two of them is defined:`a.jar && b.jar`

*Because when the two packages have classes of the same name, the order is important.*

I tried to change the order in the **pom.xml**. No effect.

Seems to have something to do with **parent** in **pom.xml**, So I want to ask the exact answer.

Comment: `I tried to change the order in the pom.xml. No effect.` Try changing the order in IDE module's `*.iml` file. The https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-155703 may be related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ultimately due to the **order** in which the **maven** parses the **dependency**.

*One's own dependency (recurrence, including dependency) takes precedence over the dependency inherited from the parent.*

*the IDEAJ startup application or the spring-boot runs the application, Their classpath order depends on the parsing order provided by the maven.*